# Can i declare multiple variables in JavaFX FXML?

Tags: variables, javafx, fxml

It's not a "problem" that i am currently facing, everything works just fine, but i am a neophyte programmer and i worry that my code is too long and not user-friendly (not that i plan to give it away, it's worthless but if later i come back to it i would appreciate an easier understanding).

It's precisely in the controller of my main window FXML. I declare all my variables like this :

```
@FXML
private TableColumn colFirstName;
```

But even if it was easy to understand at first, i now have a file with 30+ variables like this. Since i put a space between each FXML variables (personnal preference i guess), with the comments the controller contains 150 lines of variable declaration only !

So i tried to declare multiple variables like this :

```
@FXML
private Foo foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4;
```

But only the last one can be used. The other ones are simply useless (SceneBuilder gives an error, if i launch it's a null exception)

Would you give me some tips for that ? What would a "pro" do with that ? Is there a way to avoid this or do i have to go with it ? My teacher says that "the fewer, the better". Taking 150 lines just to declare 30 variables of only 5 types seems ... not "optimum" ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English !

Comment: This is really just a matter of personal style preference, but I always create each variable on a separate line. There's nothing to stop you putting the annotation (`@FXML`) on the same line as the rest of the declaration, of course.

Comment: Also, the style you showed in the second example (though I don't like it) seems to work just fine. When I tested, all fields got properly initialized.